# Make home router accessible via Internet

Tags: iptables, internet, busybox, router

**Setup:**

I have logged in to a Huawei router using ssh. It's a busybox system with ash. Tools available are ifconfig, iptables and some others.

**What I want to do:**

Making all ports (http, ssh, telnet, etc.) available to the internet.

```
# iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:113 reject-with tcp-reset 
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
3    INPUT_DOSFLT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
4    INPUT_SERVICE_ACL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
5    INPUT_URLFLT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
6    INPUT_SERVICE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
7    SPI_FILTER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
8    INPUT_FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    FWD_DOSFLT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
2    FWD_MACFLT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
3    FWD_URLFLT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
4    FWD_IPFLT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
5    FWD_NATSERVICE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
6    FWD_SERVICE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
7    SPI_FILTER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
8    FWD_FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    SPI_FILTER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
3    OUTPUT_DOSFLT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ACC_FLT (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DMZ_FLT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWD_DOSFLT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    syn_flood  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN 
2    ping_flood  icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 

Chain FWD_FIREWALL (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWD_IPFLT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWD_MACFLT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWD_NATSERVICE (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    PORTMAP_FLT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
2    UPNP_PORTMAP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
3    DMZ_FLT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWD_SERVICE (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports 53,67,68,80,443 
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports 53,67,68,80,443 
3    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports 143,110,25 
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports 143,110,25 
5    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports 21,115,23 
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports 21,115,23 
7    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWD_URLFLT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWFLT_NULL (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_DOSFLT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    syn_flood  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN 
2    ping_flood  icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 

Chain INPUT_FIREWALL (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
2    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:23 
3    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8081 
4    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain INPUT_SERVICE (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport ports 53,67,68 
2    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports 631 
3    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,ACK/SYN 
4    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:500 
5    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:4500 
6    ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
7    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:67:68 
8    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:6050 
9    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:0 
10   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:50000:50020 

Chain INPUT_SERVICE_ACL (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain INPUT_URLFLT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:53 dns_flt match homerouter.cpe 

Chain IPFLT_BLACKTABLE (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IPFLT_WHITETABLE (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain MACFLT_BLACKTABLE (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain MACFLT_WHITETABLE (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_DOSFLT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain PORTMAP_FLT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.1.2         tcp dpt:22 

Chain SPI_FILTER (3 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID 
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 

Chain UPNP_PORTMAP (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain URLFLT_BLACKTABLE (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain URLFLT_WHITETABLE (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ping_flood (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 100/sec burst 150 
2    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain syn_flood (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 100/sec burst 150 
2    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Do you *really want to do that? In my home router I took care only the VPN connection is available to the outside.

Comment: Yes, I really want to do this and I know the risks.

Comment: Maybe I will only make the vpn connection available, but I think it's almost the same command for all ports

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Making all ports (http, ssh, telnet, etc.) available to the internet"? Do you want something on the router itself to respond to connections from the WAN side, or do you want to forward all traffic to something on the LAN side (consumer router "DMZ")? Or something else? Please be specific.

Comment: Router shell should be accesible anywhere. Just the router, not a network device.